# File context policy update vs. usage race condition

Tags: selinux, ansible

I have an Ansible playbook where one task adds a SELinux file context and the following tasks is supposed to use that new context - i.e. fix the file context of a directory if necessary.

When I run the playbook it looks like the second task still uses the old file context policy. That means it doesn't fix the directory's context as expected. Only after I run the playback a second time the context is fixed.

Example output from first run:

```
TASK [web : add file contexts] ****
# Addition to semanage file context mappings
+/srv/fubar(/.*)?      a      system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0
changed: [example.org]

TASK [create webroot] **********
--- before
+++ after
@@ -1,7 +1,7 @@
 {
     "path": "/srv/fubar",
     "secontext": [
-        "unconfined_u",
+        "system_u",
         "object_r",
         "var_t",
         "s0"

changed: [example.org]
```

Whereas the immediate playbook re-execution yields:

```
TASK [web : add file contexts] ****
ok: [example.org]

TASK [create webroot] *******
--- before
+++ after
@@ -3,7 +3,7 @@
     "secontext": [
         "system_u",
         "object_r",
-        "var_t",
+        "httpd_sys_content_t",
         "s0"
     ]
 }

changed: [example.org]
```

Further executions don't yield any changes, as expected.

The Ansible tasks look like this:

```
- name: add file contexts
  sefcontext:
      target: '/srv/fubar(/.*)?'
      setype: httpd_sys_content_t
      state: present

- name: create webroot
  file:
      state: directory
      dest: /srv/fubar
      owner: juser
      group: juser
      mode: '0755'
      setype: _default
      seuser: _default
```

What am I missing here?

Is there some race-condition when updating the SELinux file contexts like that, in general?

When looking it the log files, there is some SELinux message saying that the policy was reloaded - right before the next task is executed, though. This matches also the `sefcontext` [module documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/sefcontext_module.html) which states that SELinux policy reload is enabled, by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really depends on how Ansible is invoked.

Even with SSH multiplexing (enabled by default) and SSH-pipelining (often recommended), Ansible (as of 2.9.11) re-logins and runs each task in a new Python process.

In that environment, the added file context is immediately visible in the file task.

However, when you run the playbook with the [Mitogen connection plugin](https://mitogen.networkgenomics.com/ansible_detailed.html#overview) enabled, the consecutive tasks are executed in the same Python process. And then the file context change is actually cached at the process level.

It's cached because Ansible calls `selinux.matchpathcon()` (in `selinux_default_context()`, `module_utils/basic.py`) to get the default file context. It turns out that `matchpathcon()` is deprecated and internally caches all file contexts on the first call. A possible fix would be for the `sefcontext` module to call [`selinux.matchpathcon_fini()`](https://manpath.be/f32/3/matchpathcon) after it invokes the policy reload.

This happens with the [Mitogen](https://mitogen.networkgenomics.com/ansible_detailed.html#overview) connection plugin because it's very good at reusing ssh connections and python processes. Which is a good thing because this dramatically speeds up playbook execution.

#### See Also

[Similar issue in Puppet](https://tickets.puppetlabs.com/browse/PUP-2169) - since Puppet runs as an agent - all tasks always run in the same process - and Puppet also used the `matchpathcon()` API without flushing its cache when file contexts changed in the system's SELinux policy.

Comment: cf. my ansible bug report: https://github.com/ansible-collections/community.general/issues/888